# A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to run below query in sql server 2008 .

`select geography::STGeomFromText(Shape.STAsText(),4326).STArea() from PARCELS_AZ`

I am getting the execption -

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "geography":  System.ArgumentException: 24200:
>   The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance.
>   System.ArgumentException:     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ConstructGeographyFromUserInput(GeoData
>   g, Int32 srid)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType
>   type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)

I am trying to calculate area for polygons, but getting this exception.

How can I change my query to calculate area so that area will be calculated only for valid geometries?

Comment: Why are you calling `STAsText()` just to convert it back into a `geography` type?

Comment: Because I want to calculate area in square meters. I am converting Shape.STAsText() to geometry taking 4326 as second argument.

Comment: But why can you not just call `Shape.STArea()` directly?

Comment: Because I want to calculate area in square meters.By using Shape.STArea() area is not coming in square meters. I am converting Shape.STAsText() to geometry taking 4326 as second argument.I have tried to calculate the area in three ways . (1) Area =length*breath (2) Using ArcMap (3)Using Sql server .  All three are giving nearly same results.  But I have to calculate area for 1 million records.Thats why I want to use sql queries to calculate area.